# APNS register remote push notification when app not running?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

In android , we can use service and broadcastreceive. Anyone has any idea to do that registers the remote-push notification when app is not running(never lunched) in iOS ?
 (Though i think it is impossible.)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible.  The app must be run to request notification permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This would make no sense in iOS. Registering for APNS requires user confirmation and needs to be subjected by your app.

If your app is not running - it can't do anything. And if you don't subject it, the user can't confirm.

As of iOS8 some functionality is enabled by default. For details you should refer to WWDC 2014 content.